# jQuery Validation in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery, validation

i have a strange situation may its a easy fix or something i may be missing but here is the question.

i have a asp.net form with master page and my validation works great without any problem but the problems starts when i try to hook my click event to the server side,

**here is what i meant:**
i have a form with few fields on it and if the form is empty than it should STOP submitting, otherwise allow me to execute the server side script

but its not happening, even my form is in invalid state (i do get error message saying i have to enter the required fileds) but still executing my server side script.

i would like to execute my server side script only if the form is in valid state.

here is my code:
**my master page**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>jQuery Validation in ASP.NET Master Page</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**my content page:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
      <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#aspnetForm").validate({
                rules: {
                    <%=txtName.UniqueID %>: {
                        minlength: 2,
                        required: true
                    },
                     <%=txtEmail.UniqueID %>: {                        
                        required: true,
                        email:true
                    }
                }, messages: {
                    <%=txtName.UniqueID %>:{ 
                        required: "* Required Field *", 
                        minlength: "* Please enter atleast 2 characters *" 
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" MaxLength="30" runat="server" /><br />
    Email: <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" onclick="SubmitTheForm();" Text="Submit" />
</asp:Content>



function SubmitTheForm() {
    SaveTheForm();
}


function SaveTheForm() {
    debugger;
    var request = buildNewContactRequest();

    ContactServiceProxy.invoke({ serviceMethod: "PostNewContact",
        data: { request: request },
        callback: function(response) {     
            processCompletedContactStore(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, errorMsg, thrown) {
            postErrorAndUnBlockUI(xhr, errorMsg, thrown);
        }
    });  
    return false; 
}
```

**i have tried both ways**

1)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            SaveTheForm();
    });
});
```

2)

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" onclick="SubmitTheForm();

  function SubmitTheForm() {
        SaveTheForm();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're posting your data without checking if the form is valid or not
I think you have to use something like this

```
function SubmitTheForm() {
    if ($("#aspnetForm").valid()) SaveTheForm();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm giving you bad advice. Forget my previous entry. What is the SubmitTheForm() method? You're using the jQuery validation plug in, so you should just need to attach the validation stuff to the form and all should be right with the world.

Comment: validated - where does it coming from?, its throwing me an error

Answer (score 0):

I think your button onclick needs to be

```
return SaveTheForm();
```

As in:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" onclick="return SubmitTheForm();" Text="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to put the jQuery code script in the Head ContentPlaceHolder